# undefined this.setState inside 'then' block

Tags: reactjs

I have the following function, `this.setState` is usable outside of the `.then` method.

```
  autoWork(e) {
    this.setState({ showWaiting: true });
    actions.autoSubmit(exampleVarOne, exampleVarTwo).then(function (results) {
      dbAction.fetch().then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          const responseData = response.data;
          this.setState({ disabledButton: true })
          this.setState({ showWaiting: false });
        }
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ showWaiting: false });
      });
    });
  }
```

However I get the following error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of
> undefined

for this line of code `this.setState({ disabledButton: true })`

`this` is not accessible inside the `then` block? How can I update the state inside the `then` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMAScript 6 introduced arrow functions, In your case, the anonymous function would not able to access `this` until it bound. They don't have their own `this` binding. Instead, this is looked up in scope just like a normal variable.

You should replace the function in the first `.then` call with an arrow function, as well as the function in `.catch`:

```
 autoWork(e) {
    this.setState({ showWaiting: true });
    actions.autoSubmit(exampleVarOne, exampleVarTwo).then((results) => {
      dbAction.fetch().then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          const responseData = response.data;
          this.setState({ disabledButton: true })
          this.setState({ showWaiting: false });
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ showWaiting: false });
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's because `function`'s can set their own `this` context. You can easily avoid that by using an arrow function instead:

Change:

```
    actions.autoSubmit(exampleVarOne, exampleVarTwo).then(function (results) {
```

to

```
    actions.autoSubmit(exampleVarOne, exampleVarTwo).then((results) => {
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204346/typescript-error-an-outer-value-of-this-is-shadowed-by-this-container