# accessing 'this' in exported function - typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, this

I am trying to understand the following error that i am getting once trying to access/pass 'this' in an exported function, I have the following code:

```
export async function main() {
try {
    console.log(this)
catch (e: any) {

}
```

which give me this error when trying to compile :

```
src/main.ts:55:32 - error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.

55      console.log( this);
                                  ~~~~

src/main.ts:28:23
    28 export async function main() {
                             ~~~~
    An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container.
```

I don't understand why i have problem accessing it - should 'this' be the function scope ? or the global object ? who is shadowing this variable and how can i work around that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript error: An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204346/typescript-error-an-outer-value-of-this-is-shadowed-by-this-container)

Comment: It depends on how you call it. The code above does not determine what `this` is. This is why you get the error: depending on how you call it `this` can be different things.

Comment: i am calling from another file ( since it is an exported function) simply by running 'main()' 

`(async () => { main()})();`

Comment: In this case `this` will be either `undefined` (in strict mode) or the global object. If you call the function with neither `main.call(someThisValue)` nor as object property like `const obj = { main }; obj.main()` there is no point in using `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from `noImplicitThis` compilation option.
You can either remove this option (not recommended) or declare the type for `this` such as:

```js
export async function main(this: unknown) {
    try {
        console.log(this);
    } catch (e: any) {

    }
}
```

Playground link: https://tsplay.dev/mLLpbm

Comment: but what is the source of the error ? i mean passing this with unknown just declare `this` as an argument to the function. why i can't access `this` without declaring it ?

Comment: Because there is no definition what type `this` should be otherwise... If you write `main.call(123)`, the `this` will be a `new Number(123)`, and if you write `const obj = { main }; obj.main()` then `this` will be `obj`, and if you are in strict mode and just write `main()` then `this` will be `undefined`, etc.